# How can I calculate the percentage of an item that appears in multiple columns representing years for different groups in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: python, sql, ssms

I have a dataset with an id and each id has a series of codes for each year in a range. I am trying to calculate the percentage of codes that show up in two consecutive years. It looks something like the one below.

| id | year | codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 786 |
| 1 | 2020 | 345 |
| 1 | 2021 | 786 |
| 1 | 2021 | 345 |
| 1 | 2022 | 345 |
| 1 | 2022 | 23 |
| 1 | 2022 | 34 |
| 2 | 2020 | 345 |
| 2 | 2021 | 345 |
| 2 | 2022 | 345 |
| 2 | 2022 | 23 |

I am using group by to get calculations for the unique ids, but I am not sure how to cleanly make the calculations. I am looking for a result that will work looks like:

| id | 2020 - 2021 | 2021 - 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100% | 50% |
| 2 | 100% | 100% |

### Edit

I also need to know the codes that do not make it from year to year. For my example this would be:

| id | 2020-21 gaps | 2021-22 gaps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 786 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

Is something like this possible in SQL?

### Edit

I have a python portion of my pipeline. Would it be easier in python?

Comment: Can you explain the figure `33%`?

Comment: it should have be 50%. It is corrected.

Comment: Just in case, could you add your dbms in tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but it's a bit tricky. One of the key point is to sort by id and code, not by year: using window functions, it allows to identify the changes for each.

I propose you a solution built using MySQL, using [Common Table Expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/); one and the following logic:

- Identify code and year changes from one line to another
- Use this intermediate result to calculate the basis counts (and reject values that comes only ones - to be adapted if necessary)
- Mark changes - identify rows where a repetition occur
- Count values to be considered (ie for each id, number of codes that appear continuously)
- calculate summary / percentages (to be adapted to your dbms and results formatted accordingly)

Here is the code for my proposition:

```sql
with
order_data as (
  SELECT id, code, year,
         lag(code) over (partition by id, code order by id, code desc, year) as prev_code,
         lag(year) over (partition by id, code order by id, code desc, year) as prev_year,
         lead(year) over (partition by id, code order by id, code desc, year) as next_year

    FROM my_data
),
total_count as (
  SELECT id, count(distinct code) as nb_code
    FROM order_data
   WHERE prev_year IS NOT NULL OR next_year IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY id
),
detect_repeat as (
  SELECT id, code, year, prev_code, prev_year,
         CASE
           WHEN code = prev_code THEN year - prev_year
           ELSE -1
         END as repeat_code
    FROM order_data
),
repeat_count as (
  SELECT id, year, prev_year,
         CONCAT (prev_year, '-', year) as period,
         count(distinct code) as nb_repeat
    FROM detect_repeat
   WHERE repeat_code = 1
   GROUP BY id, year, prev_year
)
  SELECT t.id, period, nb_repeat, nb_code,
         CONVERT(decimal(5,2), ((coalesce(nb_repeat, 0) * 1.0) / nb_code) * 100) as repeat_ratio
    FROM total_count as t
    LEFT JOIN repeat_count as r on t.id = r.id
```

Please feel free to play this code and adapt it thanks to [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=0730441829746cf162146de6b4cd7605)

**EDIT:** I updated the query to adapt it to SQL Server and to add ids where there are no changes.

If you really need to build some columns for the periods, instead of dedicated row, you'll need to set it up in a transactional program according to your dbms

Comment: I think this could be helpful, but I also need to know the codes that were not present from year to year. There is a python portion of my pipeline. Do you think it would be easier to calculate this there if I want to keep a list of such codes?

Comment: Yes you're right, I should have included a 0% for the 3rd ID I included in the fiddle - and yes you will probably include this in this query

Comment: I updated the query and the fiddle to adapt it to SQL Server. For your second need (the edited part of the first post), finally you will need an additional query, but you should be able to adapt it from the first one above - please ask if you need some additional support